# module filter with multiple expressions

Tags: commcare

Is it possible to add multiple properties in a module filter?

I want to filter a module on two properties:

1. user/role
   (count(instance('commcaresession')/session/user/data/role) > 0) and (instance('commcaresession')/session/user/data/role= 'interviewer')
2. case/property
   ./data/property != '1'

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that using an `and` or an `or` operator. To combine your expression you can do this:

```
(count(instance('commcaresession')/session/user/data/role) > 0) and (instance('commcaresession')/session/user/data/role= 'interviewer') and ./data/property != '1'
```